# Do temp table writes lock the database in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, concurrency, temp-tables, system.data.sqlite

According to the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5):

> Multiple processes can be doing a SELECT at the same time. But only
>   one process can be making changes to the database at any moment in
>   time...

What happens when 2 processes are creating / inserting / updating / deleting / dropping *temp tables* at the same time? Do those actions also lock the database?

I'm using the .NET port System.Data.SQLite if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html says that a database that does not participate in a transaction does not get a journal. In any case, modifying temp tables puts a write lock only on the TEMP database, which is private per process.